# Where are native libraries executed from?

Tags: android-ndk

Simple question, where are native libraries in the native portion of Android executed from? I have a library that references the path of "cacert.pem", so where should this file be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native libraries are executed from /data/data/*package_name*